# Modal reseting the redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I made a react/redux application using firebase, but when i open the modal and close it or add a product all data of application are set hidden

App.js file

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import FormModal from "./components/Modal/FormModal";
import Modal from "./components/Modal/Modal";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import ProductReducer from "./reducers/ProductReaducer";
import Card from "./components/Card/Card";

function App() {
  const store = createStore(ProductReducer);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const onShowModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };
  const onHideModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Header onShowModal={onShowModal} />
        <Layout>
          <Card />
        </Layout>
        <Modal show={showModal}>
          <FormModal show={showModal} onHideModal={onHideModal} />
        </Modal>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Modal.js file

```
    import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Modal = (props) => {
  const states = useSelector((state) => state);
  console.log(states);

  return (
    <div
      className={
        props.show
          ? `bg-slate-400 fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center z-1`
          : "hidden"
      }
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

FormModal.js file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addItem } from "../../actions/ProductActions";
import { collection, addDoc, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const FormModal = (props) => {
  const [infoProduct, setInfoProduct] = useState({
    title: "",
    url: "",
    description: "",
    price: 0,
  });

  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const targetValue = evt.target.value;
    const key = evt.target.name;

    setInfoProduct((old) => ({
      ...old,
      [key]: targetValue,
    }));
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const db = getFirestore();

  const addProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "webjump-store"), productItem);
      dispatch(addItem(infoProduct));
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
  };

  const productItem = {
    produto: {
      title: infoProduct.title,
      url: infoProduct.url,
      description: infoProduct.description,
      price: infoProduct.price,
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className={props.show ? "bg-slate-300 w-64 p-6 z-1" : "hidden"}>
      {" "}
      <button type="button" className="float-right" onClick={props.onHideModal}>
        X
      </button>
      <form className="flex flex-col items-center">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input
          className="my-3"
          type="text"
          name="title"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label>Url</label>
        <input
          className="my-3"
          type="text"
          name="url"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label>Description</label>
        <input
          className="my-3"
          type="text"
          name="description"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <label>Price</label>
        <input
          className="my-3"
          type="text"
          name="price"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button
          className="my-4 p-4 bg-slate-200 border-2 border-solid border-black"
          type="button"
          onClick={addProduct}
        >
          Add Product
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormModal;
```

I have no ideia o it can be.
When i do a console.log in my redux state it appers to be empty.
But when i reload the page all data from fire store appears again.